# adding foreign key to the tables in laravel 5.1

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, laravel-5.1, database-migration

I've spent too much time to figure out why migrate doesn't work.I almost read all posts and questions in this context but I couldn't find a solution .

I want to create tables which some columns are foreign key. I tested if I hadn't foreign key all tables  would create without any errors.
this is my first migration:

> ```
> class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
> {
>     /**
>      * Run the migrations.
>      *
>      * @return void
>      */
>     public function up()
>     {
>         Schema::create('user_info_tbl', function ( $table) {
>             $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
>             $table->increments('userID',true);
>             $table->integer('guID')->unsigned();
>             $table->boolean('isRegister');
>             $table->string('carrierName');
>             $table->string('city');
>             $table->string('resolution');
>             $table->string('osVersion');
>             $table->string('ram');
>             $table->string('macAddress')->unique();
>             $table->rememberToken();
>             $table->timestamps();
>         });
>
>
>
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * Reverse the migrations.
>      *
>      * @return void
>      */
>     public function down()
>     {
>         Schema::drop('users');
>     }
> }
> ```

second migration :

```
class CreateAdsInfoTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('ads_info_tbl', function ( $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('adsID',true);
            $table->integer('userID')->unsigned();
            $table->boolean('isValid');
            $table->integer('cost');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->timestamp('createAt');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('ads_info_tbl', function ( $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->foreign('userID')->references('userID')->on('user_info_tbl');
        });
        }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        //
        Schema::drop('ads_info_tbl;');
    }
}
```

when I remove third migration all tables create correctly but after adding third migration error comes:

```
>php artisan migrate
Migration table created successfully.



  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'adsdatabase3.#sql-8e8_2c' (errno: 150) (SQL: alter table `
  user_reg_tbl` add constraint user_reg_tbl_guid_foreign foreign key (`guID`) references `user_info_tbl` (`guID`))


  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'adsdatabase3.#sql-8e8_2c' (errno: 150)
```

this is my third migration :

```
    class CreatRegistration extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('user_reg_tbl', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('userRegID');
            $table->integer('guID');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('lastName');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->boolean('isAdmin');
            $table->boolean('isSuperAdmin');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('guID')->unsigned()->references('guID')->on('user_info_tbl');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {            Schema::drop('user_reg_tbl');
    }
}
```

I've tried different options like adding INNODB engine to all my tables.
Or I had read somewhere that we must add unsigned() to avoid these errors.
something is too annoying all table create in mysql otherwise I get error!. but when I want to delete the table that error related to ,mysql error comes : unknown table, and I had to delete whole database and renew one.
I don't know what is wrong.

I'm using Laravel 5.1 in phpStorm environment.

Comment: ok, i saw $table->foreign('userID')->references('userID')->on('user_info_tbl'); but then, you had $table->foreign('guID')->unsigned()->references('guID')->on('user_info_tbl'); tried moving ->unsigned() to **$table->integer('guID');** ? So, it'll looked like $table->integer('guID')->unsigned().

Comment: I had tried the option you said before , but now I'll  check it again @Tezla

Comment: still there is error @Tezla

Comment: ok, this might be stupid (i can't figure any other reason), could you mention your migration filenames? it might looked like TIMESTAMP_name.php. You had to ensure the referenced one to be created before the referencing migration.

Comment: @Tezla when i remove foreign key statement and delete old database then migrate all tables create with out error it means that name of migration is okay yes?

Comment: no, your first migration had to enter database earlier before being referenced with. If we define no relations between migration, naming issue won't be problem - but on the other had, relations matter. Laravel import migrations to database following the timestamp of the php file.

Comment: one thing that is too odd is whether i have error or not tables create :| @Tezla

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95551/discussion-between-tezla-and-n-93).

Comment: yes the order is : 1)2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php 2)2015_11_18_162556_createAdsInfoTable .php 3)2015_11_18_170008_createAdsTransaction.php